# Набухли почки

Tags: этимология, омонимы

Как известно, почка - это орган растения, из которого развивается новый побег. Но при этом почки же - это орган животных, отвечающий за выделение жидкости из организма. Ни внешне, ни по функциям ничего общего между этими органами нет. Разве что, кроме шуток о том, что у алкоголиков "по весне набухли почки".
Почему же и орган растений, и орган животных называется одинаково?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это сейчас слова звучат одинаково, а когда-то звучали по-разному. Утрата редуцированных сблизила внешний облик.

ПОЧКАI (орган). Др.-рус. суф. производное от исчезнувшего пока (ср. диал. и др.-рус. опока "глина"), производного (с перегласовкой е/о) от *pekti (> печь). К развитию значения ср. печень, кашубск. povarka. Первоначально "то, что пекут, готовят для еды, однокоренные- печень, печь"/

ПОЧКА II (на дереве), русск.-цслав. пъщька,  укр. по́чки "внутренности; тыквенные семечки", словен. реčkà "плодовая косточка", реčèk, род. п. реčkà "косточка винной ягоды, плода". От праслав. корня, производного от *pъta-бугорок, припухлость.